# setting mamp ports to 80 and 3306

Tags: mysql, apache, dreamweaver, mamp

I have both apache and mySQL running with the default MAMP ports (8888 and 8889 respectively) and everything seems to work, but when I switch the ports to 80 for Apache and 3306 for mySQL, the mySQL server is unable to restart.

I am trying to setup MAMP to run on these ports because apparently this is optimal for developing in dreamweaver... Thus, given that I would like to have the ideal dev environment for dreamweaver, is there a way around using the 3306 port? Or, what could the potential problems be?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just in case anyone is having the same problem, here is how I fixed it:

I opened the Activity Monitor program and selected "All Processes"
Next I search for "mysqld" in the search text field. There is a good chance that you have an instance of mysql running and you have to find it and hit quit process.
Restart MAMP and you should be all set.

Comment: This not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

[i posted my solution here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226066/ubd-process-interfering-with-mamp-at-port-80?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
but will it annoy the editor gods to re-post? i found this works so clearly and consistently that it's worth evangelizing.

fix courtesy of [Abhinav Sood](http://www.abhinavsood.com/working-apache-port-80-localhost-in-mamp-or-mamp-pro/).

1. Launch MAMP. Open Terminal by typing terminal into Spotlight (Command + Space).
2. Open MAMP Preferences (Command + , ) and click on Reset MAMP Ports 
   (Port 8888 and Port 8889 for Apache and MySQL respectively). 
   Click on OK.
3. Switch to the terminal. Type `sudo apachectl stop` to shutdown the system Apache.
4. Restart MAMP.
5. Open MAMP Preferences once again and click on Set to Default Apache and MySQL ports. This will set the Apache and MySQL ports to 80 and 3306 respectively.
6. Switch to the terminal. Type `sudo apachectl restart` to restart Apache.
7. Switch back to MAMP and click on Open Start Page (or go to `http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English` in your browser)

And you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

I configured httpd.conf.
In that file just replace:

Listen 80

for

Listen localhost:80

restart mamp. It worked for me.

Comment: phpmyadmin is still convinced that it should be listening at 8889. how to fix this? and start page doesn't load as it should

Answer (score 1):

@Mazal

Finally I found your great great solution of fixing this localhost:80 and apachectl issue. However, the issue will resume back when after re-start against!!!!!!

So fix this goto perference-->when quiting MAMP--> [uncheck] the box stop server.

this will keep the port setting to localhost:80 and apachectl in green light.

cheers!