# NodeJS Error connect ECONNREFUSED about mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect my mysql database but i can not i got error that : **Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8889**

My code :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    port:"8889",
    user:"root",
    password:"root",
    database:"turktakvim_mobil"
});

var server = app.listen(8000,function(){console.log("localhost successfull");
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
});

con.connect(function(error){
    if(error) console.log("error : "+error);
    else console.log("database successfull");
});
```

and i got this output : 
 
**localhost successfull 
 error : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8889**

I also checked my MAMMP settings , everything is okay

[image: a screenshoot from my work]

[image: mammp settings]

Comment: have you tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in your `mysql.createConnection` object?

Comment: yes and same error again , nothing changed

Comment: Probably an issue of port mapping as the user below notes, or you may have more than one instance of `mysqld` running. See this question for details on diagnosis and resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476162/1720873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I execute your code like:: it worked 
I think issue is with you mysql connection

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    port:"3306",
    user:"root",
    password:"root",
    database:"test"
});

[execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwKtP.png)

Comment: oh okay okay i check my mammp mysql port again from mysql preferences , there is writing 3306 
i copied your code and executing , it worked! thank you so much
problem was about my mammp - mysql port